# If Conditions on jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to apply if..elseif.. condition on multiple UI sliders. Practically I want that certain slider show/hide depending on the `ui.value` but the if condition is not working correctly. A fiddle can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/XWRDZ/

Code below:

HTML

```
<div id="label">Postpaid</div><br />
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>
<br />
<div id="slider-range-max-2"></div>
```

JS

```
<script>
var packageselection = 0;

 $(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').hide(); 
    $('#slider-range-max-2').hide(); 
});

  $(function() {
    var labelArr = new Array("Postpaid", "Hybrid", "SIM Only");
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      min: 0,
      max: 2,
      value: 0,
      step: 1, 
      change: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#label").html(labelArr[ui.value]);
        packageselection = ui.value;
        if ( packageselection = 1 ){
                $('#slider-range-max-2').show(); 
            }
        else if ( packageselection = 2 ){
                $('#slider-range-max-2').hide(); 
            }   
      }

    }); 
  });

  $(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max-2" ).slider({
      min: 1,
      max: 3,
      value: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
                }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Thanks so much for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

equal to is `==` or `===` not `=` (thats declaration)

```
if ( packageselection == 1 ){
            $('#slider-range-max-2').show(); 
        }
    else if ( packageselection == 2 ){
            $('#slider-range-max-2').hide(); 
        }
```

Comment: Manyyy Thanks for your help its working perfectly :)

Comment: No problem, you can accespt the answer :)